# Compare hashMap values

Tags: java, hashmap, compare

Im practicing some interview questions but have no idea how to compare hashMap values. The premise is that you have a magazine with strings. You have to cut out the appropriate number of  characters out of the magazine to form a ransom note. I've managed to add both the characters and the number of occurrences of the characters to a hashMap but how do I compare the two hashMaps to determine I have enough letters.Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Magazine = {g=2,  =14, d=2, e=2, a=4, n=1, o=5, l=4, m=1, .=1, k=1, I=2, h=2, i=6, w=1, T=1, u=1, t=2, s=3, r=1, y=2}
Ransom = {w=1,  =3, o=1, l=4, k=1, I=1, y=1, i=2}

```
String mag = "this is what I said Im going to do. i really like you a lot";
        String ransom = "i will kill you";

        Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        Map<Character,Integer> ransomMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < mag.length() -1; i++)
        {
            char c = mag.charAt(i);
            if(!map.containsKey(c))
            map.put(c, 1);
            else{
                int value = map.get(c);
                map.put(c,++value);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);

        for(int i = 0; i < ransom.length()-1; i++ )
        {
        char c = ransom.charAt(i);
        if(!ransomMap.containsKey(c))
            ransomMap.put(c,1);
        else
        {
            int value = (ransomMap.get(c));
            ransomMap.put(c,++value);
        }
        }
        System.out.println(ransomMap);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check each letter in your ransom note and see if there are enough in the newspaper:

```
boolean enoughLetters(Map<Character, Integer> magMap, Map<Character,Integer> ransomMap) {
    for( Entry<Character, Integer> e : ransomMap.entrySet() ) {
        Character letter = e.getKey();
        Integer available = magMap.get(letter);
        if (available == null || e.getValue() > available) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Just so I understand the solution clearly,for each entry in the ransomHashMap, you get the key(letter) first then look for the exact same key in the magazine hashmap whilst pulling out the value attached. If the magazine value is null or less than the current entry value boolean false. Should it not cause some sort of error if the magazine key does not exist.

Comment: If the magazine key doesn't exist then you will have `available == null`.

Comment: +1, though you can use `containsKey()` if you try to avoid null checks like I do: `if (!magMap.containsKey(letter) || magMap.get(letter).getValue() > available) return false;`

Comment: I usually don't do `containsKey()` if I'm going to end up getting the key anyway. Possibly premature optimization, but it's out of habit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer works.  But I solved this by using (Test Driven Development) TDD.  Here are the tests I came up with:

```
@Test
public void whenMagazineHasLessCharactersThanRansomThenYouCanCreateRansom() {
    assertFalse(canMakeRansom("abcdef", "abcdefg"));
}

@Test
public void whenMagazineHasSameCharactersOfRansomThenYouCanCreateRansom() {
    assertTrue(canMakeRansom("abcdefg", "abcdefg"));
}

@Test
public void whenMagazineHasSameCharactersOfRansomButInDifferentOrderThenYouCanCreateRansom() {
    assertTrue(canMakeRansom("abcdefg", "gfedcab"));
}

@Test
public void whenMagazineHasSameCharactersOfRansomButHasMoreThenYouCanCreateRansom() {
    assertTrue(canMakeRansom("aabbccdefg", "agfedcab"));
}

@Test
public void whenMagazineHasSameCharactersOfRansomButRansomHasMoreThenYouCantCreateRansom() {
    assertFalse(canMakeRansom("aabbccdefg", "aaaaagfedcab"));
}
```

The left parameter is the magazine and the right is the ransom.  This is too large to post as a comment so I'm using an answer.

```
private boolean canMakeRansom(String magazine, String ransom) {
    Map<Character, Integer> magList = createCharCountMap(magazine);
    Map<Character, Integer> ransomList = createCharCountMap(ransom);
    return magHasAtLeastTheseCharacters(magList, ransomList);   //Andrew's implementation
}

private Map<Character, Integer> createCharCountMap(String chars) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (char c : chars.toCharArray()) {
        if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
            charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            charCountMap.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    return charCountMap;
}
```

Comment: Test Driven Development, which means (simplistically) to define your test cases prior to development.

Comment: I don't come up with all these cool acronyms for good programming practice...but anyway, where is your `canMakeRansom` function?

Comment: You're still missing `magHasAtLeastTheseCharacters`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly. you can probabaly check for all the characters [ a-z A-Z 0-9 !@#$%^&*(*)(_+{:<}">? ].

Comment: I do not think you understood the question - he was asking how to compare the two maps he got, whether he has enough letters in his `map` to generate the `ransom` from it

Comment: ya. looping over the key of ranson makes much sense :)